# Solving $A = 94\left(1 - e^{-0.43 B}\right)^{0.52}$ for $B$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I am not a regular math user. I need to solve an equation to apply on timeseries variables.

I have value of $A$ but don't have value of $B$ variable. Here, time series variables (mentioned as variable $A$) with known values are canopy cover values (range $40$ to $100$). Whereas variable $B$ (unknown values) are the leaf area index (LAI). The output LAI values (variable $B$) might be in $0.5$ to $10$.

The equation:
$$ A = 94\left(1 - e^{-0.43 B}\right)^{0.52}$$
(In MS Excel: `A = 94*POWER(1-EXP(-0.43*B),0.52)}`)

> What would be the equation that can be applied to get value of "$B = \text{expression}$"?

This might be quite simple, but for me it's not. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  We can indeed help you with a solution.  A couple of things would improve your post.  One is to use mathematical notation, which is [briefly introduced here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).  The other is to explain in a few words what motivates your problem (a little more context than "timeseries variables").  I can try to convert your Excel formula; please review to make sure I've not unintentionally changed your meaning.

Comment: Here time series variables (mentioned as variable A) with known values are canopy cover values (range 40 to 100).  whereas variable B ( unknown values) are the leaf area index (LAI). Thanks a lot @hardmath for converting the equation in to the standard format. it is perfectly transformed.

Comment: The LAI value might be in 0.5 to 10. thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation is easily solved for $B$ in terms of $A$ by "reversing" each of the operations that appears on the right-hand side:

$$ A = 94(1 - e^{-0.43 B})^{0.52} $$

$$ A/94 = (1 - e^{-0.43 B})^{0.52} $$

$$ (A/94)^{1/0.52} = 1 - e^{-0.43 B} $$

$$ e^{-0.43 B} = 1 - (A/94)^{1/0.52} $$

$$ -0.43 B = \ln (1 - (A/94)^{1/0.52}) $$

Therefore:

$$ B = \frac{\ln (1 - (A/94)^{1/0.52})}{-0.43} $$

This derivation of $B$ and especially the last line make it clear that we want $A$ to be nonnegative and less than $94$ in order for there to be a corresponding real value of $B$.  Indeed the last line gives $B$ as the ratio of two negative numbers, so that $B\gt 0$ when $0 \lt A \lt 94$.  This is mostly consistent with what the Question says about "canopy cover values" except those in the range for $A$ at or above $94$.

Comment: Thanks a lot @hardmath for stepwise explanation and final equation for B.